# use linq method wcf ria

Tags: silverlight

i have this method in my domainService

```
     public IQueryable Getbl()
   {
       var qer = from t in this.ObjectContext.lignes_bl
                 from t0 in this.ObjectContext.entete_bl
                 where
                   t.NO_BL == t0.NO_BL
                 orderby
                   t.NO_BL,
                   t.NO_LIGNE
                 select new
                 {
                     IDentete_bl = t0.IDENTETE_BL,
                     NO_BL = t0.NO_BL,
                     DATE_BL = t0.DATE_BL,
                     FAC_AVOIR = t0.FAC_AVOIR,
                     REF_BL = t0.REF_BL,
                     CODE_CLIENT = t0.CODE_CLIENT,
                     NOM_CLIENT = t0.NOM_CLIENT,
                     ADRESSE = t0.ADRESSE,
                     CODE_PAYS = t0.CODE_PAYS,
                     VILLE = t0.VILLE,
                     CODE_POSTAL = t0.CODE_POSTAL,
                     ZONE = t0.ZONE,
                     TEL_FAX = t0.TEL_FAX,
                     CODE_ADL = t0.CODE_ADL,
                     NOM_ADL = t0.NOM_ADL,
                     ADRESSE_ADL = t0.ADRESSE_ADL,
                     CODE_POSTAL_ADL = t0.CODE_POSTAL_ADL,
                     VILLE_ADL = t0.VILLE_ADL,
                     MT_TTC_BL = t0.MT_TTC_BL,
                     CODE_PAYS_ADL = t0.CODE_PAYS_ADL,
                     TEL_FAX_ADL = t0.TEL_FAX_ADL,
                     REM = t0.REM,
                     CODE_REGLEMENT = t0.CODE_REGLEMENT,
                     NO_FACTURE = t0.NO_FACTURE,
                     DATE_FACTURE = t0.DATE_FACTURE,
                     CODE_COMPTA = t0.CODE_COMPTA,
                     SITE = t0.SITE,
                     CODE_COMMERCIAL = t0.CODE_COMMERCIAL,
                     NBR_COLIS = t0.NBR_COLIS,
                     NOM_TRANSPORTEUR = t0.NOM_TRANSPORTEUR,
                     FACTURE_DIRECTE = t0.FACTURE_DIRECTE,
                     MOIS_FACTURE = t0.MOIS_FACTURE,
                     CLE_SITE_MOIS_FAC = t0.CLE_SITE_MOIS_FAC,
                     CLE_SITE_FD_CC = t0.CLE_SITE_FD_CC,
                     CLE_SITE_FD = t0.CLE_SITE_FD,
                     CLE_SITE_FD_CC_EDIT = t0.CLE_SITE_FD_CC_EDIT,
                     ARCHIVAGE = t0.ARCHIVAGE,
                     NO_TVA_CL = t0.NO_TVA_CL,
                     numero = t0.numero,
                     Bis = t0.bis,
                     voie = t0.voie,
                     P_identite = t0.P_identite,
                     p_numero = t0.p_numero,
                     p_du = t0.p_du,
                     p_par = t0.p_par,
                     nais_du = t0.nais_du,
                     nais_ville = t0.nais_ville,
                     nais_dep = t0.nais_dep,
                     nais_pays = t0.nais_pays,
                     num_siren = t0.num_siren,
                     id_bon_ademe = t0.id_bon_ademe,
                     poids_ademe_vhu = t0.poids_ademe_vhu,
                     CODE_BROYEUR = t0.CODE_BROYEUR,
                     IDlignes_bl = t.IDLIGNES_BL,
                     CODE_CLIENT_LI = t.CODE_CLIENT,
                     NO_BL_LI = t.NO_BL,
                     DATE_BL_LI = t.DATE_BL,
                     FAC_AVOIR_LI = t.FAC_AVOIR,
                     CODE_ARTICLE = t.CODE_ARTICLE,
                     NO_VEHICULE = t.NO_VEHICULE,
                     DESIGNATION = t.DESIGNATION,
                     QTE = t.QTE,
                     PU_HT = t.PU_HT,
                     REM_LI = t.REM,
                     CODE_TVA = t.CODE_TVA,
                     TAUX_TVA = t.TAUX_TVA,
                     NO_LIGNE = t.NO_LIGNE,
                     TYPE_ARTICLE = t.TYPE_ARTICLE,
                     LIB_LIBRE = t.LIB_LIBRE,
                     DESI_ARTICLE = t.DESI_ARTICLE,
                     CODE_GARANTIE = t.CODE_GARANTIE,
                     NO_FACTURE_LI = t.NO_FACTURE,
                     CODE_REGLEMENT_LI = t.CODE_REGLEMENT,
                     SITE_LI = t.SITE,
                     LIB_MODELE = t.LIB_MODELE,
                     PA_HT_TTC = t.PA_HT_TTC,
                     PU_NET = t.PU_NET,
                     PU_TTC = t.PU_TTC,
                     code_id_article = t.code_id_article,
                     site_stockage = t.site_stockage,
                     sans_trait_haut = t.sans_trait_haut,
                     nom_article_unique_demonter = t.nom_article_unique_demonter,
                     code_ademe_ligne = t.code_ademe_ligne,
                     poids_ademe = t.poids_ademe,
                     type_article_ademe = t.type_article_ademe,
                     consistance = t.consistance,
                     conditionnement = t.conditionnement,
                     nombre_carcasse = t.nombre_carcasse,
                     num_vehicule_entretien = t.num_vehicule_entretien,
                     num_immat_vehi_entretien = t.num_immat_vehi_entretien
                 };
       return qer.AsQueryable();
```

and i have this code in button ,the problem is does not contain a definition for Getbl ?

```
    DomainService1 testContext = new DomainService1();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var res = testContext.Getbl();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getbl returns an enumeration of an anonymous type.  Anonymous types have only `internal` accessibility hence getbl is not included in service since that would in effect mean it would have return a list of type instances that should not be exposed publically.

Create a public class the has the list of Properties you want to return and include a new instance of this public class in your `Select` projection rather than using an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to AnthonyWJones answer:

Use [LoadOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423147%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) to get the data from the server:

```
LoadOperation<Customer> loadOp = this._customerContext.Load(this._customerContext.GetCustomersQuery());
CustomerGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
```

Note: Your method will have an appendix "Query" which RIA adds to Query methods.